# Struggling to wrap my head around this Database Query

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I am completing Stanford's Relational Algebra course and am having a hard time understanding one of the questions, although I have got the answer.

Here is the schema:

```js
/* Delete the tables if they already exist */
drop table if exists Person;
drop table if exists Frequents;
drop table if exists Eats;
drop table if exists Serves;

/* Create the schema for our tables */
create table Person(name text, age int, gender text);
create table Frequents(name text, pizzeria text);
create table Eats(name text, pizza text);
create table Serves(pizzeria text, pizza text, price decimal);

/* Populate the tables with our data */
insert into Person values('Amy', 16, 'female');
insert into Person values('Ben', 21, 'male');
insert into Person values('Cal', 33, 'male');
insert into Person values('Dan', 13, 'male');
insert into Person values('Eli', 45, 'male');
insert into Person values('Fay', 21, 'female');
insert into Person values('Gus', 24, 'male');
insert into Person values('Hil', 30, 'female');
insert into Person values('Ian', 18, 'male');

insert into Frequents values('Amy', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Ben', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Ben', 'Chicago Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Cal', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Cal', 'New York Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Dan', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Dan', 'New York Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Eli', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Eli', 'Chicago Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Fay', 'Dominos');
insert into Frequents values('Fay', 'Little Caesars');
insert into Frequents values('Gus', 'Chicago Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Gus', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Hil', 'Dominos');
insert into Frequents values('Hil', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Hil', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Ian', 'New York Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Ian', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Ian', 'Dominos');

insert into Eats values('Amy', 'pepperoni');
insert into Eats values('Amy', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Ben', 'pepperoni');
insert into Eats values('Ben', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Cal', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'pepperoni');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'sausage');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Eli', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Eli', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Fay', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Gus', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Gus', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Gus', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Hil', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Hil', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Ian', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Ian', 'pepperoni');

insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'pepperoni', 12);
insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'sausage', 12);
insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'cheese', 9);
insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'supreme', 12);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'pepperoni', 9.75);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'sausage', 9.5);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'cheese', 7);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'mushroom', 9.25);
insert into Serves values('Dominos', 'cheese', 9.75);
insert into Serves values('Dominos', 'mushroom', 11);
insert into Serves values('Straw Hat', 'pepperoni', 8);
insert into Serves values('Straw Hat', 'cheese', 9.25);
insert into Serves values('Straw Hat', 'sausage', 9.75);
insert into Serves values('New York Pizza', 'pepperoni', 8);
insert into Serves values('New York Pizza', 'cheese', 7);
insert into Serves values('New York Pizza', 'supreme', 8.5);
insert into Serves values('Chicago Pizza', 'cheese', 7.75);
insert into Serves values('Chicago Pizza', 'supreme', 8.5);
```

I am struggling to wrap my head around Question 6. The question reads: **Find all pizzas that are eaten only by people younger than 24, or that cost less than $10 everywhere they're served.**

Now, I understand the query. It is basically divided into two parts:

1. Pizzas eaten by people younger than 24
2. Pizzas costing less than 10$

I even understand the answer i.e. the Union of (difference between all pizzas served and pizzas costing greater than equal to 10$) and (difference between all all pizzas eaten by people and those eaten by people greater than equal to 24 years of age)

```
(\project_{pizza} (Serves) \diff \project_{pizza} (\select_{price>='10'} Serves))
\union
(\project_{pizza} (Eats) \diff \project_{pizza} (\select_{age>='24'} Person \join Eats))
```

However, I cannot understand why the opposite query does not give the same answer i.e. Union of (pizzas costing less than 10$) and (pizzas eaten by people less than the age of 24).

```
(\project_{pizza} (\select_{price<'10'} Serves))
\union
(\project_{pizza} (\select_{age<'24'} Person \join Eats))
```

Why does the second query give an answer that is different from the first. According to me, they should both give the same answer.

All replies appreciated.

Comment: LEFT JOIN people to pizza then WHERE people < 24 yrs old and cost < $10

Comment: Hey Matt the Ninja, could you please elaborate. I am more interested in the logic than the query itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query finds pizzas that

**does not cost** more that $10 **anywhere**, 
or **is not eaten** by **any** people aged 24 or above,

while your last query fins pizzas that

**is sold** for less than $10 **somewhere**, or
**is eaten** by **some** people below 24.

These queries will give diffrent result for pizzas that are sold for less than $10 at some places and more than $10 other places, or that are eaten by some people younger than 24 and some older.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. That makes sense now! I would upvote you but I don't have enough rep. Thanks!!

Comment: @philosopher It is nice to be able to help. If you accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark), you will gain reputation (+ 2) as well.